# Glass BSDF Casting Dark Colour / Shadows

Tags: fluid-simulation

Blender 2.82:

I am baking out a fluid sim and mesh, and applying a glass BSDF shader for the transparency.  When rendering out, it gives a dark tint to the glass material, on top of the surface it is touching.  When "in air" the water material looks clear and clean as it should, however on the bottle and floor, it looks dark.

my light path bounce settings are:

Total: 12
Diffuse: 5
Glossy: 5
Transparency: 5
Transmission: 15
Volume: 5

World setting is a light blue (no HDR) and strength is 1.
I have 1 sun lamp.

I know its not the transmission settings as this causes the black areas when light is not passing through the glass shader, hence why I've already increased this.

so what else is the issue here?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Could you please post it as two separate questions? It keeps the site easy to navigate. Thanks.

Comment: @JachymMichal. Will do, sorry.